# "uninitialized constant" error with a a different name of the class while accessing has_many through fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For this piece of code at my partial:

```
<% if build.optical_drives.blank? %>
```

I am getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant Build::OpticalDrife
```

Although I didn't mistype `OpticalDrife` anywhere.

I have this following relationship:

```
class OpticalDrive < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :optical_drive_builds
    has_many :optical_drives, through: :optical_drive_builds
end
class OpticalDriveBuild < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :optical_drives
#   has_many :builds
end
class Build < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :optical_drive_builds
  has_many :optical_drives, :through => :optical_drive_builds
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened due to the singularization and pluralization error of rails. As word like `knives` has a singular form `knife`, rails mistakenly singularized `drives` as `drife`.

I have fixed this problem by adding following in my `config/initializers/inflection.rb`:

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'drive', 'drives'
 end
```

More at: http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/interesting-problem-fixed-with-rails-inflections/

Answer (score 3):

We have a option called [`:class_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) :

> Specify the class name of the association. Use it only if that name can’t be inferred from the association name. So has_many :products will by default be linked to the Product class, but if the real class name is SpecialProduct, you’ll have to specify it with this option.

```
has_many :optical_drives, :through => :optical_drive_builds, class_name: 'OpticalDrive'
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work without explicit `class_name`?

Comment: Sure, it's inflections inside Rails

Comment: @nsave Yes, look the other answers to understand why the automatic infer didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

[**Inflections**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)

To give context as to why this error appears, the clue is in the name:

> **Build::OpticalDri*f*e**

This would *only* happen if Rails is taking `drives` and trying to turn it singular.

Although this works well in most cases, the fact remains that it can sometimes get it wrong.

The workaround is to define the `class_name` explicitly:

```
has_many :optical_drives, through: :optical_drive_builds, class_name: "OpticalDrive"
```

This sets the `class_name` *explicitly*, which will save the interpolation issue.

---

However, the *real* way to fix it is to define the interpolation in your app (`sadaf2605`'s answer) and [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation):

```
#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      optical_drive: OpticalDrive
```

Comment: Yeah, that is another way. +1 . I took actually what Doco said as I _quoted_ above.